# Como verificar campos a null em sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

O trigger que tenho que fazer:

> Um utilizador só pode atribuir classificação a uma oferta se a tiver adquirido (reserva com `estado = pago`). Por outro lado um dos dois atributos classificação e comentário tem que ser `NOT NULL`.

O que tenho feito:

```
create trigger T10 on CLASSIFICACOES instead of insertas begin

--inserir apenas se tiver adquirido um produto/serviço (reserva de estado = pago)
insert into CLASSIFICACOES
    select 
      i.ID_UTILIZADOR, 
      i.ID_OFERTA, 
      i.ID_CLASSIFICACAO, 
      i.DATA_DA_CLASSIFICACAO, 
      i.CLASSIFICACAO, 
      i.COMENTARIO
    from inserted i
    where exists ( 
      select 
        [ESTADO_DA_RESERVA]
      from RESERVAS r, 
      where 
        r.[ESTADO_DA_RESERVA] = 'Pago'
    )

-- verificar se tem ou comentário ou classificação `NULL`
-- (aqui agora quero verificar se algum dos campos é `NULL` para não poder inserir caso o sejam)
```

Está certa a maneira de pensar para criar este trigger? Se sim, como faço para verificar se os campos são `NULL`?

Tabelas que interessam:

```
CLASSIFICACOES (
  id_utilizador (pk), 
  id_oferta (pk), 
  id_classificacao (pk), 
  data_da_classificacao, 
  classificacao, 
  comentario
)

RESERVAS (
  id_reserva (pk), 
  id_meio_pagamento (fk), 
  data_de_reserva, 
  data_de_pagamento, 
  estado_da_reserva, 
  total
)

UTILIZADORES(
  id_utilizador (pk), 
  id_empresa (fk), 
  login, 
  email, 
  primeironome, 
  ultimonome, 
  nif, 
  bloqueado
)
```

Comment: Você não pode inserir essa clausula de `NOT NULL` no `where` onde você ja verifica se ja esta pago?

Comment: @Giovane não porque são tabelas diferentes, a tua sugestão seria logo no where tentar criar solução onde verificasse se há existe nulo nesse campo?

Comment: Sim, é só fazer uma busca com `JOIN`. Essas tabelas se relacionam, certo?

Comment: Não a tabela reservas liga a uma tabela de ofertas e essa de ofertas é que liga a uma de classificações... Daí eu não saber bem como fazer as querys para fazer este trigger @Giovane

Comment: Coloca ai as estruturas, só as partes que se relacionam, que eu te ajudo.

Comment: @Giovane editei na resposta, espero que seja o que pediu

Comment: Qual o banco de dados??

Comment: @Giovane obrigado pela formatação da pergunta (ainda não sei bem como por as perguntas bem arranjadas

Comment: Como assim? @Giovane

Comment: Qual o banco de dados que esta usando? MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Sever @Giovane

Comment: Certo... como você vai saber se o usuário efetuou o pagamento se na reserva não tem o ID dele?

Comment: Entendendo "um dos dois atributos classificação e comentário tem que ser NOT NULL" como os dois poderem ser simultaneamente NOT NULL é só utilizar OR (A IS NOT NULL OR B IS NOT NULL). Se não puderem ser simultaneamente NOT NULL então você precisará utilizar o operador XOR, que não existe diretamente mas pode ser reescrito com uma combinação de OR, AND e NOT.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve duas FKs na tabela `reservas`:

- Uma que aponta para `utilizadores`, senão você não sabe quem fez a reserva
- Uma que aponta para `ofertas`, senão você não sabe qual oferta foi reservada

Depois disso, o `where` na sua trigger pode ser facilmente alterado para fazer a consistência:

```
where exists ( 
  select 
    [ESTADO_DA_RESERVA]
  from RESERVAS r, 
  where 
    r.[ESTADO_DA_RESERVA] = 'Pago'
   and r.id_utilizador = i.id_utilizador
   and r.id_oferta = i.id_oferta
)
```

A tabela `reservas` me parece representar uma relação N-para-N entre `usuarios` e `ofertas`, por isso precisa ter essas duas FKs.